# FormClosing shows Exit Confirm MessageBox two times

Tags: c#, winforms, exit, messagebox, formclosing

I am facing a problem on form closing. It's shows my exit confirm message box 2 times and and ask 2 times "Are you sure to exit?":

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to exit. Confirm?", "Rest O Rant", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    Application.Exit();
    MessageBox.Show("Thank You For Using Rest O Rant Software.", "Closing message!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
else
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Activate();
}
```

Comment: *Always* use the `e.CloseReason` to find out what you should do.  You for example never *ever* want to show that message box when it is CloseReason.WindowsShutDown.  And as you found out, you don't want to show it either when it is CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall.  It is only ever good enough when it is CloseReason.UserClosing

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
MessageBox.Show("Thank You For Using Rest O Rant Software.", "Closing message!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

Application.Exit();
```